# Fill the interior of path keeping line width visible

Tags: iphone, ios, core-graphics, quartz-graphics, cgpath

I am trying to fill the interior of shape but no use. It only strokes path but do not fill with hello colour. I have googled but nothing works as fill not working. Guide me what I am doing wrong.

```
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextAddPath(ctx, pathi);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, [UIColor yellowColor].CGColor);
CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 3.0);
CGContextSetLineCap(ctx, kCGLineCapSquare);
CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing(ctx, NO);
// CGContextStrokePath(ctx);
CGContextDrawPath(ctx, kCGPathFillStroke);
```

**Edit:** The code for pathi is

```
- (CGMutablePathRef)getPath {

if (self.shapeType == NOSHAPE) {
    return nil;
}

[lineHeight removeAllObjects];
[linesArray removeAllObjects];

CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();

switch (self.shapeType) {
    case Rectangle_SHAPE:{
        Line *l1 = [[Line alloc] initWithLineName:LineName_a_S
                                      starttPoint:self.bound.origin
                                         endPoint:CGPointMake(self.bound.size.width, self.bound.origin.y) scalingFactor:1.0
                                     linePosition:LINE_DIRECTION_HORIZONTAL];

        [lineHeight addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:l1.lineLength]];
        [linesArray addObject:l1];

        Line *l2 = [[Line alloc] initWithLineName:LineName_c_S
                                      starttPoint:CGPointMake(self.bound.size.width, self.bound.origin.y)
                                         endPoint:CGPointMake(self.bound.size.width, self.bound.size.height) scalingFactor:1.0
                                     linePosition:LINE_DIRECTION_VERTICAL];

        [lineHeight addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:l2.lineLength]];
        [linesArray addObject:l2];

        Line *l3 = [[Line alloc] initWithLineName:LineName_b_S
                                      starttPoint:CGPointMake(self.bound.size.width, self.bound.size.height)
                                         endPoint:CGPointMake(self.bound.origin.x, self.bound.size.height) scalingFactor:1.0
                                     linePosition:LINE_DIRECTION_HORIZONTAL];

        [lineHeight addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:l3.lineLength]];
        [linesArray addObject:l3];

        Line *l4 = [[Line alloc] initWithLineName:LineName_d_S
                                      starttPoint:CGPointMake(self.bound.origin.x, self.bound.size.height)
                                         endPoint:self.bound.origin scalingFactor:1.0
                                     linePosition:LINE_DIRECTION_VERTICAL];

        [lineHeight addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:l4.lineLength]];
        [linesArray addObject:l4];

        CGPathAddPath(path, NULL, [l1 getPath]);
        CGPathAddPath(path, NULL, [l2 getPath]);
        CGPathAddPath(path, NULL, [l3 getPath]);
        CGPathAddPath(path, NULL, [l4 getPath]);

        [l1 release];
        [l2 release];
        [l3 release];
        [l4 release];
        break;
    }
    default:
        break;
}

return path;
```

}

I am creating other shapes too and path is made in same way. **Line** class gives me line from the start and end points. Please tell me if there is something i am missing.

Comment: What are you seeing? Only the red outline? (images of what you are actually seeing + expected could be useful)

Comment: I tried and i was able to get the border and fill color separated by using the same code.
I used this for your "pathi"
CGPathRef pathi = CGPathCreateWithEllipseInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100), nil);

now my guess is either your path is not a large rectangle, or you are using width size of larger value which is hiding your fill color.

Comment: @Puneet I have also checked by drawing rectangle and it is working but not for my pathi. pathi spams over full rectangle with margin of 1.5. I have also tried default width but that is also not working. if you want to see how I am creating pathi, I will share code.

Comment: Yes please. share the code where you are creating pathi

Comment: Why not just use `CGContextFillPath` and `CGContextStrokePath`?  Then you could fill and draw the bordering line.  Make sure you do them in that order though.

Comment: @Putz1103 kCGPathFillStroke do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I, too reccomend what user Putz suggest in his comment:

Store the path, first fill it (`CGContextFillPath`) , change the stroke color, then stroke (`CGContextStrokePath`) it.
I have done that, this works fine.